# paths when using \input

Tags: input, paths

I tried the following:

```
\chapter{Chapter One}
\input{C:/Users/ocuk/MyDocuments/Introduction/Introduction.tex}
```

I have already renamed "My Documents" to "MyDocuments" but is still doesn't seem to work?

Baz

Comment: Where is your principal file located?

Comment: you can surround filenames with `"` if they contain spaces but better really to just use `\input{Introduction/Introduction}` which is easier and more portable, just arrange that your documents folder is in your TEXINPUTS path

Comment: Also The default security settings prevent reading files with absolute file paths.

Comment: @ Nicoguaro by principle file do you mean the one with call to \input?  it is at C:/Users/ocuk/MyDocuments/Thesis

Comment: @David how to I find out what my TEXIMPUTS path is?

Comment: in texlive `kpsexpand \$TEXINPUTS` (or `kpsexpand $TEXINPUTS` depending on your commandline) in miktex it is probably viewable in a menu somewhere?

Comment: move your Introduction folder below your Thesis folder then you don't need anything special at all, `\input{\input{Introduction/Introduction}` will just work as a local path from your main document

Comment: Thanks that works I copied the Introduction (as a complete folder) into the introduction folder. Trouble is it isn't showing any of the graphics files? Do I need to do something extra for those?

Comment: \includegraphics and \input work the same way you should give the path from the main file even if the \includegraphics is in a file in a subfolder

Comment: Similarly it's unable to open the bibtex file?

Comment: Ah no got it sorry to be so dumb! Seems to work best if I just copy everything to the workig directory tex/image and bidtex files